# Is there an API-method to reverse an array

Tags: java, arrays, reverse

I am looking for a method to reverse an `array` of `char`s.

If I use an `ArrayList<Character>` to store my chars, I can use the `Collections.reverse(List<T>)`-method.

```
List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
  list.add((char) (97 + i));
}
Collections.reverse(list);
```

But how can I reverse an `array` of `char`s? Is there any API-method or do I have to implement it by myself? `Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(char[]))` is useless.

```
char[] input = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
char[] out = new char[input.length];
for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  out[i] = input[input.length-i-1];
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: how abt just write a simple reverse method? it is just a for loop

Comment: Why not loop from `input.length -1` till 0 instead of reversing array?

Comment: `char[] input = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };
   String s = new StringBuilder(new 
                 String(input)).reverse().toString();
   char[] out = s.toCharArray();`

Comment: premature duplicate close: the OP asked for a reversal of chars based on *JDK methods*. 0xflotus: nice solution provided by @ShahzadIftikhar

Comment: @wero Exactly! This is quite different from that.

Comment: I found a `reverse(char[])`-method for `array`s in class `ArrayUtils` in the Apache Commons Lang. This is also a good option.